# FreeRTOS+STM32F4+CPP stuck when call the vTaskDelay

Tags: c++, freertos

I'm using STM32F405RGT + HAL driver + FreeRTOSv9. And the code is C++. First of all, when I wrote the code of C, there is no problem. But C++, something wrong.

entry point in main.cc

```
extern "C" int main(void) {

  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();

  xTaskCreate(startup, "startup", STARTUP_TASK_STACK, NULL, STARTUP_TASK_PRIO, NULL);
  vTaskStartScheduler();

  return 0;
}
```

And "startup" task is

```
static void startup(void *param) {

  Config::GetInstance().Init();
  Command::GetInstance().Init();

  while (1) {

    trace("startup\r\n");
    vTaskDelay(M2T(1000));
  }

  vTaskDelete(nullptr);
}
```

In "Command::GetInstance().Init()", create another task and in that task, just vTaskDelay(_500ms) and printf("something\r\n"). That's all.

If I use "HAL_Delay()" in the "startup" task, everything is OK. In the console, I can see two strings - "startup" and "something". But when I use the "vTaskDelay()" in the "startup" task, it should stuck in the "vTaskDelay()" and system calls "HardFault_Handler()".

I really don't know why.

Comment: You didn't provide full code sample, so it's hard to tell what's wrong - probably something with the code you did not include. Verbal description of what some functions do is usually not sufficient, especially when it comes to unexpected behavior such as HardFault. Having said that, all I can suggest with the data provided is to track the HardFault yourself. For that have a look here: http://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should not increment the Systick correctly in the interrupt handler. You should check your interrupt tick or check a special define in the file freertos_config.h at the end of file to be compatible freertos with the hal_delay.

Comment: His problem is using extern C statements with C++ code in them. Lose the extern "C"  statement and right your code with C++ only. unles your trying to import C statements.